# sympyについて質問です「TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float」

Tags: python, sympy

画像の赤丸の部分を(Φ+2π/3)に変更したいです。

この部分を変更しようと思っています。

```
B_vectors = [A_vectors[i] + B*(unit_vectors[i] * cos(thetas[i])-ez*sin(thetas[i]) ) for i in range(3)]
```

単純に `B*(unit_vectors[i+(2.0*np.pi/3.0)]` のように変更しても以下のエラーが出ます。どうすればよいのでしょうか？

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float
```

プログラムの全文を載せます。

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import *

init_printing()

# 単位ベクトルとか角度の定義
angles = symbols("phi_0 phi_1 phi_2")# 原点から肩部への方向を表す角度
thetas = symbols("theta_0 theta_1 theta_2")# モーターの角度(±90deg)
unit_vectors = [Matrix([cos(angles[i]),sin(angles[i]),0]) for i in range(3)]
ez = Matrix([0,0,1])

# パラメータ(実数)
params = [(A,130.0),(B,200.0),(C,400.0),(D,130.0)]
params.append((angles[0],2.0*np.pi/3.0*0))
params.append((angles[1],2.0*np.pi/3.0*1))
params.append((angles[2],2.0*np.pi/3.0*2))
params.append((x,0))
params.append((y,0))
params.append((z,400))

# 各座標の計算
A_vectors = [A*x for x in unit_vectors]
B_vectors = [A_vectors[i] + B*(unit_vectors[i] * cos(thetas[i])-ez*sin(thetas[i]) ) for i in range(3)]
D_vector = Matrix([x,y,z])
C_vectors = [D_vector + D * unit_vectors[i] for i in range(3)]
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: そのエラーメッセージを使って検索するか、Web翻訳サービス等で翻訳してみれば直ぐに分かるのでは？ それが正しいかどうか不明ですが、その部分を`B*(unit_vectors[int(i+(2.0*np.pi/3.0))]`のように整数に変換して試してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: `unit_vectors` は `for i in range(3)` で 3項目の listなので, 各々を指し示すのは `[0],[1],[2]` だけで, `[i+(2.0*np.pi/3.0)]` だと当然エラー (範囲外)。また `unit_vectors[i]` に加算するのも違います (それぞれの項目は `Matrix` なので「行列」に対する加算になってしまう)

Comment: (続き・補足) 例えば `unit_vectors[0] +1` だと前者が行列なのでエラー。`unit_vectors[0] +Matrix([1,2,3])` のようにするならば加算可能